# Will I fly further if I intermittently pull out my paraglider?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

When jumping from a high place, will I get more distance if I pull out my paraglider and keep it out until I run out of stamina? Or is it better to intermittently pull out my paraglider in short bursts that use up less stamina?

Comment: I don't have concrete evidence, but it certainly feels that way. You cannot gain forward momentum if you're just gliding, it has a max speed. If you have any "air mobility" clothes, I think you move further forward just diving than gliding. Of course, you'll want to start as high up in the air as you can to make use of this.

Answer (score 4):

You can only go further horizontally if you have the extra height to support it.

Here's a diagram I drew to illustrate this.

[image: A graph of the distance travelled by use of paraglider.]

When moving with the paraglider, you are moving horizontally and vertically at a set speed - forward and down. This is a *roughly* linear path.

When taking small breaks to preserve stamina, you're still moving horizontally at the same speed, you're just also dropping downwards. This makes it easy to travel a further distance than just the paraglider alone **as long as you have the height to support it**.

Comment: In other words, by using intermittent gliding you can convert the "drop height" at the end of the red line (= the vertical height of the blue/red intersection above the X axis) into additional travel distance (= the horizontal distance starting at the intersection from of the blue line and X axis, to the intersection of the green line and the X axis).

Comment: @Flater Yup, pretty much. It's resetting your downwards velocity every time you pull out the hanglider again, so you get a *liiiiittle* bit further.